# Python: Object has a list as attribute but stores only a reference and not the list

Tags: python, list, object, attributes

I work in Python 2.4 (comes with the system).
I try to compile a list of objects.  Each Object has an attribute that is a list of other objects.  Whatever I do it seems to me that the attribute(list) stores only a reference and not the list itself. `ControlPoint.LeafPairList`  is a reference to `LeafList` but does not contain the List itself.

Later in the script I try to address the LeafPair with  ControlPoint.LeafPairList[i]
that gives me always the same settings

Any suggestions to make it work?  Thanks in advance.

Example:

```
def ReadControlPoint(fh,ControlPoint):
    line = fh.readline()
    while not line.startswith('}'):
        Scratch = line.split(' = ' )
        if Scratch[0] == 'LeafPairList':

            ReadLeafPairList(fh, LeafList)

            setattr(ControlPoint, 'LeafPairList', LeafList)


        else:
            setattr(ControlPoint, Scratch[0], Scratch[1].strip('\n"'))      
        line = fh.readline()

def ReadLeafPairList(fh, LeafList):
    del LeafList[:]
    line = fh.readline()
    while not line.startswith('}'):
        Scratch = line.split(' = ')
        Scratch = Scratch[1].strip('"\n').split()
        Leafs = LeafPair(Scratch)
        LeafList.append(Leafs)
        line = fh.readline()
```

The List looks something like that:

```
Machine = "Infinity_1"
Gantry = " 310.0"
Collimator = "   0.0"
Couch = "   0.0"
Weight = "  29.46 %"
NumberOfControlPoints = " 7"
NumberOfLeafPairs = " 80"
LeavesCanOverlap = " 1"
X2_Value = "   4.5"
X1_Value = "   4.5"
Y1_Value = "   9.0"
Y2_Value = "   9.0"
ControlPointList = {
ControlPoint = {
ControlPoint = " 0"
Weight = "   0.3"
LeftJawPosition = "   4.5"
RightJawPosition = "   4.5"
TopJawPosition = "   9.0"
BottomJawPosition = "   9.0"
LeafPairList = {
LeafPair(0) = "   0.5   0.0   0.5 -19.8"
LeafPair(0) = "   0.5   0.0   0.5 -19.2"
LeafPair(0) = "   0.5   0.0   0.5 -18.8"
LeafPair(0) = "   0.5   0.0   0.5 -18.2"
LeafPair(0) = "   0.5   0.0   0.5 -17.8"

}
}
ControlPoint = {
ControlPoint = " 1"
Weight = "   0.3"
LeftJawPosition = "   4.5"
RightJawPosition = "   4.5"
TopJawPosition = "   9.0"
BottomJawPosition = "   9.0"
LeafPairList = {
LeafPair(1) = "   0.5   0.0   0.5 -19.8"
LeafPair(1) = "   0.5   0.0   0.5 -19.2"
...
}
}
}
```

Comment: Why all the `setattr()` calls? `ControlPoint.LeafPairList = LeafList` would a lot more readable..

Comment: Please explain your problem.  You just gave three pieces of code.  Why?  What is the output you want, and what is the output you get instead?

Comment: All attributes in Python are references. They're just names in a namespace, what they're the name *for* is separate. So either there's nothing you can do or you should create copies of the list at the appropriate times. Deciding when is appropriate is necessarily an exercise for you since we don't know what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Ok thats because in Python all are references. I'll explain with a simple example:

```
>>> l = [0, 0, 0]
>>> a = l
>>> a[0] = "Changed"

>>> print (l)
["Changed", 0, 0]
>>> print (a)
["Changed", 0, 0]
```

This happend because with the statement `a=l` we have just put another name to the object `[0, 0, 0]`

To achive what you want you can use `copy` module

```
>>> import copy

>>> l = [0, 0, 0]
>>> a = copy.copy(l)  # This is the only change.
>>> a[0] = "Changed"

>>> print (l)
[0, 0, 0]
>>> print (a)
["Changed", 0, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help - copy.copy does exactly what I need